How to add superscript and subscript in correlation matrix using metan library in r studio
I have used the following code in correlation matrix using metan library in r studio,
library(metan)
View(CorrawpomF)
All <- corr_coef(CorrawpomF)
all
plot(All)

and the output of the code is like this:

how to add superscript and subscript for the ions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How to add superscript and subscript in correlation matrix using metan library
